# backbone.js empty a collection

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

I need to empty a collection, removing each item in order.

```
this.nodes.each(function(node){
  this.nodes.remove(node);
}, this);
```

Doesn't work, because as each node is removed it changes the length of the collection. Making a temporary array and then iterating over that works. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `this.nodes.reset()` unless you need `remove` event.

Otherwise:

```
var nodes = this.nodes;
while (nodes.length > 0)
    nodes.remove(nodes.at(0));
```

Comment: Yeah, I need the remove event on each node, as it is clearing other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to empty of backbone collection:

```
while ( this.catz.length > 0) this.catz.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify collection while iterating, then do it using a simple backward `for` like that:

```
var count = collection.size();
for (var i = count-1; i > -1; i--) {
    collection.remove(collection.at(i));
}
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xt635/

Answer (score 1):

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset

You can call `collection.reset();` and it'll empty the entire collection. I used it today!